# java no reconoce una clase que ya esta importada con maven apache poi

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-boot, maven, apache-poi

estoy intentando crear un excel en java con apache-poi, estoy usando spring boot y thymeleaf, ya importe las dependencias en el archivo pom.xml y lo actualizar, las dependencias si están en mi proyecto, al ejecutar el comando mvn clean install todo parece estar bien, pero a la hora de importarla a mi clase java, no la encuentra, ya intenté cambiar la versión de apache-poi a la 3.9 pero no funcionó.
dejo aquí algunos datos de referencia:
[image: me marca que no la encuentra]
esta es la clase que quiero importar pero no reconoce desde el paquete org.apache.pio
[image: esta es la clase que quiero importar pero no reconoce desde el paquete org.apache.pio]

y en las dependencias de maven si esta el jar:
[image: el jar si esta en el proyecto]

este es el código de mi pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>mx.com.telcel</groupId>
    <artifactId>detalladoVentas</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>detalladoVentas</name>
    <description>Generación de reportes sisap</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- dependency> <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId> 
            </dependency -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <!-- <scope>provided</scope> -->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- dependency> <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId> <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId> 
            <scope>test</scope> </dependency -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- START Bibliotecas necesarias para el desarrollo de reportes en Excel -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.2</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
    
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.2</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.2</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-compress</artifactId>
            <version>1.20</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.xmlbeans</groupId>
            <artifactId>xmlbeans</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- END Bibliotecas necesarias para el desarrollo de reportes en Excel -->
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

cual creen que sea el problema?. les agradezco mucho su apoyo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Responderé mi propia pregunta en caso de que a alguien le resulte útil:
No sabía qué significaba

```
<scope> runtime </scope>
```

ahora veo que este alcance indica que la dependencia no es necesaria para la compilación, sino para la ejecución. Está en el tiempo de ejecución y en las rutas de prueba, pero no en la ruta de compilación. 
**Así que la solución fue simplemente eliminar esta etiqueta.**

Answer (score 0):

En Java solo puede importar clases, no paquetes. `org.apache.poi` es un paquete y por eso te muestra el error. Para solucionarlo puedes hacer dos cosas:

**1- Importar todas las clases del paquete**

```
import org.apache.poi.*;
```

**2- Indicar el nombre de la clase que deseas importar**

```
import org.apache.poi.NombreDeLaClase;
```

Comment: si entiendo eso, lo que quiero es unsar la clase HSSFWorkbok, pero ni siquiera reconoce el paquete org.apache.poi, como lo estoy importando es: import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;

Answer (score 0):

Lo que tienes que hacer es descargarte el paquete `jar` e importarlo en tu proyecto , aqúi esta el sitio de referencia,

Referencia: https://jar-download.com/maven-repository-class-search.php?search_box=org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook

Un saludo.